# How do I add mirrored padding around a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, padding, mirror

I have a matrix and want to add padding around it but the padded values have to be mirrored.

I have tried using `A = padarray(B,[1 1],'symmetric','both');`

but it mirrors the edge values of matrix B.

Meaning if

```
  B = [1 2 3; 
       4 5 6; 
       7 8 9];
```

the result will be

```
  A = [1 1 2 3 3; 
       1 1 2 3 3; 
       4 4 5 6 6; 
       7 7 8 9 9; 
       7 7 8 9 9]
```

But I need A to look like this:

```
 A = [5 4 5 6 5; 
      2 1 2 3 2; 
      5 4 5 6 5; 
      8 7 8 9 8;
      5 4 5 6 5]
```

Is there some function like `padarray` I can use for that or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: By "mirrored" do you mean "averaged"?

Comment: No I actually meant mirroring. But I believe averaging the values would also do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `symmetric` with `[2 2]` and remove the extra parts,

```
B = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
c = padarray(B,[2 2],'both','symmetric');
c(end-1,:) = [];
c(:,end-1) = [];
c(:,2) = [];
c(2,:) = [];
```

gives,

```
c =

 5     4     5     6     5
 2     1     2     3     2
 5     4     5     6     5
 8     7     8     9     8
 5     4     5     6     5
```